# Pandas is not recognizing words, but only letters. How can I do so when I slice, it gives me the words not the letters?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, data-analysis

When I apply this function to my text, it gets cleaned but when I search for a specific word in a cell, it only gives me the letter, not the word.

```
def clean_text(x):
txt = re.sub(r'https?://\S+', '', x)
txt = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', x)
txt = ' '.join(txt.split())
return txt
```

When I try to get the first word (which should be 'future') in the following manner: df_clean.iloc[0,][0], I only get an 'F'.

How can I find words by their index in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

`df_clean.iloc[0,][0]` is going to return the 0th element of `df_clean.iloc[0,]`, which given `df_clean.iloc[0,]` is a string will be the first letter. You don't want the 0th element, you want the 0th word. If the cell had a list then what you are doing would work.

Two solutions:

1. If you wanted you could return (in `clean_text()`) `txt.split()` so you have lists
2. Or if you want you can return as you are now and search using a splice up to the first space `df_clean.iloc[0,][0:str.index(' ')]`.